# Find our the default height of the controls in Xamarin Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms

How do we find the default height of a control in **Xamarin Forms**? Say for example we have an entry for which `Height` & `Width` is not mentioned in the `XAML`.

- When this is run on all 3 OS, what's the height of this entry?
- Which unit does XF uses for height?
- Will it be different on all 3 platforms?

Comment: Thanks for the edit buddy, will keep the format in mind next time.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [`VisualElement.Height`](https://developer.xamarin.com/api/property/Xamarin.Forms.VisualElement.Height/) to get the Height of the `element`.

With regards to your questions:

> When this is run on all 3 OS, what's the height of this entry?

Due to the fact height is allocated depending on its bounds, there is no default height of a control it will just fill its boundes depending on the LayoutOptions

> Which unit does XF uses for height?

I think they use dpx although I can't find any links to back this but I will keep searching

> Will it be different on all 3 platforms?

This will not only be different for every OS this *could* be different for every device because as I explained the height is determined from the bounds of the control

The `Height` of an element depends on its bounds in the same way `Xaml` works for `WPF`

[This](http://www.wpftutorial.net/gridlayout.html) `WPF` article explains height within grids

Comment: VisualElement.Height & HeightRequest both have a default value of -1. 
I will look into that Grid Layout blog you shared to figure if we can find the height. 

Thanks

Comment: @Supreet Untill the page is rendered the value will be `-1` as you mentioned. As soon as the `page` is rendered the control can work out its height and it will have a distinct value in that property

Comment: Here is a very simple POC if someone would like to try their hands.
https://github.com/supreettare/XFControlHeightDemo

Comment: so which event are we looking at? that confirms the page has been rendered? Will try adding a button click & see if the entry height has changed by this time.

Comment: put your `entryheight.Height.ToString()` after `InitializeComponent` in the main `constructor` of the `page`

Comment: That's still -1 but I can see a value on click handler of a button. 74 for an entry in case of a Windows Phone. Will continue finding more..